# Opening the default "New Document" editor for a given ContentType from an external C# application (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: development, content-type, library

I'm currently working on integrating some SharePoint functionality to an existing C# application we have here.  Most of the requirements have be fairly easy to implement:  I'm using the ListData REST service to display documents in a Library;  I'm using Lists.asmx to Check-out and Check-in items so I can edit their metadata;  and a few other simple operations.

I'm stuck, however, on the following requirement:

> The user of the external C# application must be able to trigger the creation of new Library Documents from within the C# application.  If only one ContentType exists in the Library, open this new document window.  If multiple ContentTypes exist, prompt the user for a ContentType and open the corresponding new document window.

I've managed to fetch the list of ContentTypes for our Library and have the user select one, but after that I'm at a loss.

I can't seem to figure out how to open the default new-document Editor for any given ContentType.  (ex, a web editor for Forms; Word for docx files; Excel for xls files).

The idea is to allow the user to create the document on-the-fly as opposed to creating it beforehand and then uploading it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I ended up using the following javascript code, which is put together from the answer selected below.

```
<script language="Javascript">

var Template = "";
var SaveLocation = "";
var ProgID = "";

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(DoWorkAndClose, "sp.js");

function DoWorkAndClose()
{
    ParseUrlForVariables();
    OpenDefaultEditor();
}

function ParseUrlForVariables()
{
    var getString = window.location.search;

    if (getString && getString.length > 1)
    {
        getString = getString.substr(1);
        var variableValuePairs = getString.split("&");

        for (var i = 0; i < variableValuePairs.length; i++)
        {
            var splitPair = variableValuePairs[i].split("=");
            var variableName = splitPair[0]
            var variableValue;
            if (splitPair.length > 1)
            {
                variableValue = splitPair[1];
            }

            switch (variableName)
            {
                case "Template":
                    Template = variableValue;
                    break;

                case "SaveLocation":
                    SaveLocation = variableValue;
                    break;

                case "ProgID":
                    ProgID = variableValue;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function OpenDefaultEditor()
{
    createNewDocumentWithProgID(Template, makeAbsUrl(SaveLocation), ProgID, false);
}

</script>
```

The problem I'm having now is finding the ProgID... but that's for another question :)

Comment: You should move your update into its own answer as it's not a part of the question. It would then be polite to flag a moderator to make it community wiki, since it's based on @djeeg's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to display a page with this link:

http://hostname/_layouts/upload.aspx?List={ListId}&RootFolder={RootFolder}&ContentTypeId={ContentTypeId}&Source={Source}

If you go into list settings -> advanced, you can turn off dialogs. Then you can see the url that the "New Document" does

**UPDATE**

Is this sort of what you want:

```
createNewDocumentWithProgID('http:\u002f\u002fwssdev\u002fDocument Library\u002fForms\u002ftemplate.dotx', 'http:\u002f\u002fwssdev\u002fDocument Library', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', false)
```

http://www.novolocus.com/2009/03/04/add-a-create-new-document-link-to-a-page

http://glorix.blogspot.com/2006/11/launching-office-applications-from.html

which gets into:

core.js

- createNewDocumentWithProgIDEx
- createNewDocumentWithProgID
- createNewDocumentWithProgIDCore

init.js

```
  function StsOpenEnsureEx2(a) {
        ULSA13: ;
        if (v_stsOpenDoc2 == null || v_strStsOpenDoc2 != a) {
            v_stsOpenDoc2 = null;
            v_strStsOpenDoc2 = null;
            if (window.ActiveXObject) try {
                v_stsOpenDoc2 = new ActiveXObject(a);
                v_strStsOpenDoc2 = a
            } catch (c) {
            } 
            //non-ie stuff
        }
        return v_stsOpenDoc2
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll give this a shot.
Quick question: Is this a method for uploading existing files as new documents, or having the SharePoint webserver trigger the creation of a new document?

Comment: this is should be how to: "open the default new-document window for any given ContentType". if you need help with uploading documents via code can you create another question

Comment: Hi djeeg.  I just tried your answer.  It's not exactly what I'm looking for, though.  I'm looking for a link that will open the ContentType's default editor.  I'll modify the question to make that clearer.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: the first action when adding a new item to a document library is to upload the document, the next step is to modify the content type metadata. have you got another way to upload the document?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the analogue of visiting the Library on the SharePoint website, clicking the 'Documents' tab on the Ribbon, opening the 'New Document' drop-down, and selecting a ContentType.  This doesn't ask the user to upload a document.  Instead it opens the default editor allowing them to save a new document, or, if they change their minds, cancel the editor and leave the library unmodified.

Comment: Hi djeeg.  Yes, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  It looks like these particular implementations are for SharePoint 2007, but I'll give them a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I'll post my final work once it's ready.